# Why Collapsible header is not collapsing on dynamic scroll?

Tags: javascript

The collapsible header on my website doesn't seem to be working, and I'm wondering if it's the way I have the HTML setup? I'm trying to get the header to collapse from 125px down to 75px on scroll, but something I can't seem to get it to work. I've seen the JavaScript I'm using work on other websites, so I'm not entirely clear on what is going on with this site. Does anyone see any issues with my code? It seems like it should work fine to me. Much appreciation!

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">

    <section class="header-top" id="header-top">
    
        <div class="container content">

            <div class="top-search">
            <?php get_search_form( ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="site-branding">
                <a  href="<?php echo site_url( );?>"><img class="logo" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(  ) . '/logo.svg'?>"></a>                 
            </div>  

            <div class="header-right">

                <p class="contribute"><a href="#">Contribute</a></p>   
                
            </div>  

        </div>

    <div class="container">

            <div class="top-search">
            
            </div>

            <div class="site-branding">             
            </div>  

            <div class="header-right">                  
                
            </div>              

        </div>
        

        <div class="container header-top-block" id="titles" style="display:block">              

                <h3 class="header-block-heading-line" id="soup">
                
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" target="">
                    Hello
                    </a>
                
                </h3>

        </div>

            </div>

          </div>
      </div>
    </section> <!-- end header main -->

    <section class="header-nav">
        <div class="container borders">
            
        </div>  
        
    </section>

</header><!-- #masthead -->

.header-top {
width: 100%;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
background: $white;
position:fixed;
min-height: 125px;
&.collapsed {
    min-height: 50px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
   if(!document.getElementById("header-top").classList.contains('collapsed')){
       document.documentElement.scrollTop += 100;
       document.getElementById("header-top").className = "header-top collapsed";
     }


} else {
 if(document.getElementById("header-top").classList.contains('collapsed')){
   document.getElementById("header-top").className = "header-top";
   document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;


    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to add `}` after `&.collapsed` declaration. Also If you are using plain CSS this code will not work (you are using SCSS syntax)

Comment: Thanks for the response. There is actually nothing wrong with the code, it was a WordPress problem with my functions page.